# Where should I draw the line between view and controller in a stateful application?

Tags: winforms, model-view-controller, design-patterns

In a MVC application that lives on the web, it's easy to draw the line between view and controller - views display data to the user, while controllers gather input and route the user to views based on the input provided. But in a stateful (e.g. desktop) application, it's a bit harder to know where to draw the line, because the boundaries between operations are not as clear-cut as with a web application. So where do I draw the line?

For instance, I have a view in my application that lets the user place items on a grid. Right now I have the "place item on grid" code within the view itself (accessing the grid model to do the actual placement). But I could also put it in a controller, and pass the necessary information from the view to the controller. Neither seems like a clear-cut choice - putting the code in the view will eventually bloat the view, since there will be a large number of operations that the user can do, not just place items; but putting it in a controller just seems like an extra level of indirection, making the code harder to follow.

Or am I going about this all wrong? This is a WinForms app; my "view" is actually a form, and forms by their nature can both receive input and display information. So is the distinction meaningless? Or should I have the view be separate from the form? Or is the MVC pattern incompatible with WinForms altogether?

Answer (score 0):

MVC is a separation of concerns. It is designed to help the programmer keep details of the two areas separate. The MODEL and VIEW are collections/groupings of objects.

Each object within the VIEW may be part of the class sets BUTTON, WINDOW, TEXTAREA etc.

Each object within the MODEL will have a type corresponding to your domain such as CUSTOMER_DETAILS, ADDRESS, POSTCODE etc

The CONTROLLER object provides an interface into your MODEL objects, which your VIEW objects will use to communicate to your system. The CONTROLLER may also contain functionality that can not possibly be stored in your MODEL objects.

Traditional MVC also allows the VIEW objects to bypass the CONTROLLER and talk directly to MODEL objects, but is not recommended.

All objects conform to OO principles, and are complete and fully functional objects.